# Bracket display with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I draw lines between my brackets like shown in the image?

[image: Desired result]

This is how my current HTML looks like (below is a link to a jsfiddle).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <table class="table-condensed" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td class="col-md-5"><div class="input-group"><div class="form-control">Team 1</div><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="badge pull-right">1</span></span></div></td>
          <td class="col-md-2" rowspan="2">L</td>
          <td class="col-md-5" rowspan="2"><div class="input-group"><div class="form-control">Team 1</div><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="badge pull-right">0</span></span></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="input-group"><div class="form-control">Team 2</div><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="badge pull-right">0</span></span></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XY8Hs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine hinted me in the right direction and I made this (below is the relevant code and the updated fiddle):

[image]

```
        <td class="col-md-2" rowspan="2" style="padding:0px;">
          <div style="border-top: 2px solid #090; border-right: 2px solid #090; width:80%; height:25%; float: left; position:absolute; top:25%;"></div>
          <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid #f00; border-right: 2px solid #f00; width:80%; height:25%; float: left; position:absolute; top:50%;"></div>
          <div style="border-top: 2px solid #090; width: 20%; margin-left: 80%; float: right; position:absolute;"></div>
        </td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XY8Hs/60/

Comment: So your fiddle doesn't look exactly like your image above.  I need to do a bootstrap bracket for a friend's site and this look pretty much like it would work.  Just wanted to confirm whether I the fiddle is showing the correct result.  Thanks for the post, it'll help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I updated the fiddle and it should display the desired result again.

Comment: @Rouby hi how can i add up for one tournament in the right, let say if tournament has 4 round,

Comment: @FreddySidauruk You need to add additional rows (tr) (for each round two more) and columns (td). I have forked the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/d39hmc6k/) maybe you can figure out where / what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i have been digging on it, please check http://jsfiddle.net/dauruk0512/w6dLuvys/1/

My question is why in the third round coloum small